# bluetooth pairing in android

Tags: android, design-patterns, authentication, bluetooth

Is it possible to use a pattern based authentication(like screen lock pattern) instead of using PIN in the process of pairing two mobile devices?If so how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I certainly hope not! How about [Secured Simple Pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing_mechanisms)?
This would mean no PIN, no user interaction no "pattern".

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
The simpliest solution is display to user screen lock pattern, but in backend convert connected points into digits, then use PIN pairing.